# BigQuery: Get the first non-null value in a window?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to obtain the first non-null, non-"undefined" value in a list of values as part of a window.

Minimal example:

Given the following code:

```
SELECT
    FIRST_VALUE(
        CASE WHEN val = "undefined" THEN NULL ELSE val END
        IGNORE NULLS
    )
    OVER (ORDER BY order_key)
    AS res
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS order_key, CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS order_key, "undefined" AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS order_key, "value" AS val
) base
```

I'd expect

```
res
value
value
value
```

as the result set. Yet, the result given by the above is the following:

```
res
null
null
value
```

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#first_value) states the following:

> `FIRST_VALUE (value_expression [{RESPECT | IGNORE} NULLS])`
>
> Returns the value of the value_expression for the first row in the current window frame.
>
> This function includes NULL values in the calculation unless IGNORE NULLS is present. If IGNORE NULLS is present, the function excludes NULL values from the calculation.

Yet it seems like value_expression is not what is tested for NULLs in this case.
It seems that instead FIRST_VALUE checks NULLs against the source field, not the CASE statement (effectively *value_expression* in the above).

While the problem can easily be fixed by doing the case as part of the subquery, I'd like to better understand why this is an issue. Why does `FIRST_VALUE` not ignore the NULLs provided through the CASE statement?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to the logic above:

If you are willing to remodel your query, instead of using a window function (`FIRST_VALUE`), the same effect can be achieved via an `ARRAY_AGG(expr IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY ordering)[OFFSET(0)]`:

```
SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY_AGG(
        CASE WHEN val = 'undefined' THEN NULL ELSE val END
        IGNORE NULLS
        ORDER BY order_key
    )[OFFSET(0)]
    AS res
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS order_key, CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 2 AS order_key, 'undefined' AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 3 AS order_key, "value" AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 1 AS order_key, CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 2 AS order_key, 'undefined' AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 3 AS order_key, "value" AS val
) base
GROUP BY id
```

1. Given an empty record set for the group, `ARRAY_AGG(...)[OFFSET(0)]` will return NULL
2. Given a non-empty record set for the group, `ARRAY_AGG(...)[OFFSET(0)]` will return the first result of value_expression that is non-NULL, ordered by the ORDER BY clause provided.

The only downside (beside *maybe* performance?) is that you'll need to create a common table expression with this logic and then join it with your table that was using window functions.

Answer (score 0):

To get expected result you just need to add DESC to the ORDER BY as in below

```
SELECT
    FIRST_VALUE(
        CASE WHEN val = "undefined" THEN NULL ELSE val END
        IGNORE NULLS
    )
    OVER (ORDER BY order_key DESC)
    AS res
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS order_key, CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS val UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS order_key, "undefined" AS val UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS order_key, "value" AS val
) base
```

so the result now is

[image]

Comment: Yes, but that goes against the ordering that I want - that would give me the equivalent of LAST_VALUE according to order_key ASC, which is not what I want. I want FIRST_VALUE according to order_key ASC

Comment: if you want ASC - so result you got is exactly as expected!

Comment: If so, then why is the behaviour of`ARRAY_AGG(value_expression IGNORE NULLS)` inconsistent with `FIRST_VALUE(value_expression IGNORE NULLS)`?

Seems to me like the definition of FIRST_VALUE is pretty clear about it too - "This function includes NULL values in the calculation unless IGNORE NULLS is present. If IGNORE NULLS is present, the function excludes NULL values from the calculation."