# How to count the number of null rows preceding a specified non-null one in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, count, null

I have the data as follows: [image]

I intend to create a BQ query that would count the number of 'null' months, for each id, before a specified date (in this example the specified date is 2023-08-01 for all IDs; but I later wish to do this for cases where that date will differ per ID so if you have suggestions that would account for that I would greatly appreciate it)

The desired output would be this: [image]
e.g. before 2023-08-01 ID 111 had 3 null months, 222 had 5 null months etc

Tried checking these but its doesn't seem like the data is formatted in the same way

- [BigQuery: Get the first non-null value in a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443451/bigquery-get-the-first-non-null-value-in-a-window)
- [How to get the first not null value from a column of values in Big Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788958/how-to-get-the-first-not-null-value-from-a-column-of-values-in-big-query)
- [Count number of null rows along with the first non null row and reset the count after that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362276/count-number-of-null-rows-along-with-the-first-non-null-row-and-reset-the-count)

Closest I think I got was this - but the desired output is not exactly what I need (e.g. I don't have the option to mention the exact date from where I want the preceeding null rows to be counted from)

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/297492/count-of-null-rows-preceding-each-non-null-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several CTE are needed. The `tbl` is your raw data of the example.
The `helper` counts the `null` entries which happen in the future to this `id` and gives this value in column `count_na`. The `helper` looks up the `count_na` for the next non null item in `nr`. Next a subtraction between these values is made.

You only want to display rows which have a non null `nr`. The `qualify` clause filters only the latest entry.

Please comment out the last two filter lines. Also query each CTE for a better understanding.

```sql
With tbl as (
 Select *, case row_number() over (order by id, month) when 3 then 132 when 4 then 89 when 8 then 300 when 10 then 114 when 16 then 334 end as nr
 from unnest(['111','222'])as id, unnest(generate_date_array(date "2023-01-01",date "2023-08-01",interval 1 month)) as month 

)
, helper as  (
Select *,
countif(nr is null) over fill count_na
 from tbl
window fill as (partition by id order by month desc rows between unbounded preceding and 0 preceding) 
order by 1,2
), helper2 as
(
Select *,
last_value(if(nr is null,null,count_na) ignore nulls) over fill as last_count
 from helper
window fill as (partition by id order by month desc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) 
order by 1,2
)

Select *,
count_na - last_count as nr_null_months
from helper2
where nr is not null and last_count is not null # comment this out
qualify month=max(month) over (partition by id) # comment this out
order by 1,2
```